# Need to lock all application on the iPhone by using an app

Tags: ios

I am developing an app for one of my client,he wants me to provide a functionality to lock all available apps on his iPhone using this app,but i haven't much idea about it,i know about the screen lock like passcode app but not this one.

Please suggest some best tutorial link.

Thanks

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31154/how-do-i-password-protect-access-to-specific-apps-in-ios

Comment: @BuntyMadan, post that u linked is not discuss about programming, the OP wants to lock the apps programmatically

Comment: This may be possible in an MDM environment. MDM is used to manage enterprise information access on employee's device (Ex: BYOD). Using MDM and other software it is possible to create policies which can block certain applications on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access another app functionality from your app according to Apple guidelines so it is not possible.

Comment: Hello @iEinstein,
My client asking the same, Can you please share any link that mentioned it's not allowed as per apple guideline?
As i put much effort to find official link, But couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to lock the device programmatically. There is no available API for this.

Comment: I don't regard it as unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, Apple didn't allowed it.

Answer (score 0):

This could've been possible in Android but sorry this is impossible in iOS. Apple doesnt allow that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for an app to lock itself down. However if you have access to the device you can set up Guided Access when the app is open, preventing it from being closed. If you have an enterprise setup you are also able to set up Supervised Mode where you should be able to configure Guided Access over wifi.